# How do I get a homebrewed version of GDB working on Mac OS X Nr. 2?

Tags: c++, macos, gdb, llvm-clang, gcc4.8

I installed XCode 5.1 with clang
I installed gcc 4.8 via homebrew
Installed gdb 7.7.1 via homebrew
Using OSX 10.9.3

I compile my c++ source in eclipse kepler with a Makefile using g++-4.8 and try to debug it but when reaching a breakpoint I can't see any variables just like in this question:  [GDB says "no symbol table," but nm shows file has debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229882/)

I followed the suggestions of @Tom Tromey in the suggestions section of that question to use

```
set complaints 10000
```

in gdb and then load the file. This revealed lots of errors during loading. First I saw lots of these:

```
unhandled stab for dwarf OSO file...unhandled stab for dwarf OSO file...
```

then lots of these:

```
During symbol reading, location expression too complex.
During symbol reading, Member function "~clone_impl" (offset 414143) is virtual but the vtable offset is not specified.
```

and then a whole lot more of these:

```
During symbol reading, unexpected overlap between:
 (A) section `__TEXT.__textcoal_nt' from `<snip>/sourcefilename.o' [0x228, 0x28c)
 (B) section `__TEXT.__textcoal_nt' from `<snip>/differentsourcefilename.o' [0x268, 0x2cc).
Will ignore section B.
```

There are lots of errors where one section is being ignored in favor of another.

I used to think gdb was the culprit but I have found today that if I use llvm-g++ instead, then gdb works as expected. I was overjoyed at finding I could actually debug without using cout statements.

Another similar question: [How do I get a homebrewed version of GDB working on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556868)

I would like to fix the problem with g++-4.8 and need help. 
Most of the answers I found related to outdated versions of gdb but 7.7.1 is pretty recent and should work based on what others suggested on SO.

Comment: Same problem here, even works with llvm-g++ like you said.