# gdb not finding any debugging symbols

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debugging, gcc, gdb

I compiled a C++ program and want to debug it with gdb now. Version of gcc is `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5`, of gdb it's `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1`, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229882/gdb-says-no-symbol-table-but-nm-shows-file-has-debug-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1) doesn't seem to be a problem in my case.

Starting gdb like `$ gdb --args ./my_program /path/to/a/file` works, but it yields the following message:

```
Reading symbols from ./my_program...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

I can still run the program using `run`, but anything that requires debug symbols will fail, like setting breakpoints on lines, or using `i line` or `i locals`.

So as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1999701/2533467), I ran `$ objdump --debugging ./my_program`, and the output fills a few thousand lines, so I'm fairly certain that debugging symbols are indeed available.

There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754725/no-symbol-table-info-available) but it seems to be more related to shared libraries. Running `info sharedlibrary` in gdb shows that those don't have debugging info in my case, but I don't think I need to be concerned about that.

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7ddab00  0x00007ffff7df5660  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff74f1250  0x00007ffff74f1dc3  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0
0x00007ffff72e0a80  0x00007ffff72eb5e0  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0
0x00007ffff70a5810  0x00007ffff70b6a43  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexif.so.12
[...]
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

As suggested in the comments, I also checked for stripping:

```
$ file ./my_program
./shore_evaluate: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
BuildID[sha1]=aa85fb21d388828eced5bd0be4202a50bbba1b90, not stripped
```

*What can I do to make GDB find the debugging symbols?*

Comment: how do you compile your binary ? Check the man page for gcc normally you need to compile with `-g` or `-ggdb` generating executable with debug symbols

Comment: I'm using cmake. `-g` is in my `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, and as far as I know the output of `objdump` proves that.

Comment: try replaceing `-g` with `-ggdb` and be sure that you don't have any stripping e.g. `-s` or `-S`

Comment: Done, didn't change anything. I also tried `file ./my_program` which shows that no stripping is occuring after compilation.

Comment: @deimus It seems that I was in the wrong, the problem was actually cmake. I have added `-gddb` and cleared the cache, re-ran cmake and then re-compiled everything using make, and now the debugging symbols are all there: `Reading symbols from ./my_program...done.` Thank you so much for your help!